# Use of LOGINPROPERTY('user', 'PasswordHash) in SQL Server 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a little script to extract the password hashes of SQL Logins on 2008 and 2012 instances. Part of my code looks like this...

`SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(514), (SELECT CAST (LOGINPROPERTY('sa', 'PasswordHash') AS varbinary(256))), 2)`

When I run this in a 2012 instance, it all works fine. But when run on a 2008 instance I get a blank result. I've checked that the SQL login is valid and has a password on the 2008. The online documentation tells me that all the functions are valid between both versions.

What is the difference between the versions?

Regards,

JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash algorythms used:

- SQL Server 2012 and above use SHA2-512 (512 bytes hash)
- SQL Server 2000 to 2008 R2 use SHA1 (160 bytes hash)

You can also uses this query and DMV:

```
Select password_hash, *  From sys.sql_logins Where name in ('sa')
```

It gives the same hash that this query:

```
Select CONVERT (varchar(512),  (LOGINPROPERTY('sa', 'PasswordHash') ), 2)
```

Use this one if you want a varchar starting with `0x`

```
Select CONVERT (varchar(514),  (LOGINPROPERTY('sa', 'PasswordHash') ), 1)
```